# How to define Multiple Breakpoints in MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, breakpoints

Suppose you want to **debug a project**... but you want to **step into** all Event handlers, delegates methods etc... Is there any way how to add multiple Breakpoints at all of these locations (let's say at the start of each method)
instead of manually clicking and choosing the breakpoints?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is such a visual studio plugin for setting multiple breakpoints. See [this article](http://web.archive.org/web/20150615120431/http://naveensrinivasan.com/2010/04/27/vs2010-addinforbreakpoint/) (now removed but linked via archive.org). Also, you can copy paste a macro from [here](http://www.codeguru.com/columns/experts/article.php/c5911) into your visual studio. It also works with the 2010 edition

Answer (score 0):

Not out of the box.  I guess it may be possible to create a VS Addon that could do this but I doubt that it would be worth the effort.

Answer (score 0):

Native code had `Class::*` syntax [since at least VS2008](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/09/10/class-breakpoint-how-to-set-a-breakpoint-on-a-c-class-in-the-visual-studio-debugger/).  Probably the first case in recorded history where a debugging feature was implemented for native code *before* managed.